I add a image to a screen, there is no errors but in result it is showing like this
this is the result
name: knowledge_book
description: "A new Flutter project."

publish_to: 'none' 


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ^3.5.4

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

.
  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0




flutter:


  uses-material-design: true


assets:
  - assets/icon/
  - assets/icon/Knowladge book copy.png
  - assets/New Cat/Mala/


this is my pubspec.yaml
in this i only changed the assets, but i added every thing correct but the result is showing {Unable to load asset: -------------}
